# How to find the RSS url for a company

Tags: rss, rss-reader

This is for the purpose of studies. 
I want to extract rss feeds of Telstra company. How should I get the rss url for Telstra. 
I tried checking the page source of the company's website https://www.telstra.com.au/. However, there is no rss url.

Can someone please help me out with this.

Comment: What makes you think they even have RSS feeds? Looking at that URL, why would they even have an RSS feed for that page? There's nothing there to suggest it is frequently updated with articles.

Answer (score 0):

If the page doesn't link to an RSS feed then you:

- can guess at possible URLs (such as `/feed`) and request them until you run out of guesses or get a response that looks like RSS or Atom
- assume that **they don't provide an RSS feed**